# Sort dictionary by multiple values, where amount of values can vary

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, lambda

To come straight to the point:

```
def sortBy(dict, byWhat):

  # byWhat is a list of 1 - 10 strings, which can include any of allAttributes
  # allAttributes = ['name', 'kingdom', 'diff', 'tier', 'type', 'founder', 'prover', 'server', 'extra', 'link']
  # the lower the index, the higher the sorting priority -> byWhat = ['name', 'diff'] then sort by name first and then if names are the same by diff
  
  # dict has the name as key and then allAttributes above in order as a list for the key's value, so for example:
  # dict[Jump] = [Jump, Mushroom Kingdom, 10/10, Triple Jump, Dude, Dude2, Main Server, Cool jump description, https://twitter.com]
  # All dictionary entries have those 10 attributes, no exceptions
  
  return dict # but sorted
```

I tried for a while but where my knowledge ends is sorting by a varying size of specifiers with lambda. I can also not just call the function multiple times, because then it won't sort by two attributes, but by the last attribute the function got called with.

Comment: "I can also not just call the function multiple times" - Sure you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dict to list of (key, value) tuples and use `list.sort(key)` method and utilizing `functools.cmp_to_key` define key as compare function and then "inject" `byWhat` parameter into compare function using `functools.partial`

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key, partial

allAttributes = ["name", "age"]

def sortBy(d, byWhat):
    def cmp(a, b, byWhat):
        for k in byWhat:
            index = allAttributes.index(k)
            if a[1][index] != b[1][index]:
                return -1 if a[1][index] < b[1][index] else 1
        return 0
    items = list(d.items())
    items.sort(key=cmp_to_key(partial(cmp, byWhat=byWhat)))
    return dict(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {
        "foo": ["John", 12],
        "bar": ["Adam", 12],
        "baz": ["John", 10],
    }
    print(sortBy(d, ["name", "age"]))
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I thought `sortBy()` was supposed to be the `key` function to be used in `sort()`.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `cmp`-based sorting here?

Comment: @KellyBundy comparing to what?

Comment: @Barmar It's supposed to return the sorted dict, so I think they got this right.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows Compared to a key function that just returns a list or tuple (similar to Barman's or with itemgetter).

Comment: (There potentially *is* an advantage, I'd just like to see it pointed out :-) (oh and I'm also curious what *your* reason is)

Comment: @KellyBundy probably no advantage, I just didn't thought of it, key function returning tuple is a better solution

Comment: Could be more efficient if `byWhat` is long but items mostly differ at the first value already. The n preconputing all full tuples might be wasteful. Although repeatedly looking up the first value comes at a cost as well, especially this elaborate way.

Comment: @KellyBundy if you don't mind I will post improved version

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dict to list of (key, value) tuples, map `byWhat` into indexes and use `list.sort(key)` where `key` is lambda returning list of attributes to sort by.

```py
allAttributes = ["name", "age"]

def sortBy(d, byWhat):
    indexes = [allAttributes.index(k) for k in byWhat]
    items = list(d.items())
    items.sort(key=lambda item: [item[1][index] for index in indexes])
    return dict(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {
        "foo": ["John", 12],
        "bar": ["Adam", 12],
        "baz": ["John", 10],
    }
    print(sortBy(d, ["name", "age"]))
```